Does the prefix_header_contents in CocoaPods refer to the definition of a precompiled header that is included during compilation process?
I have a standalone iOS project that currently needs to be converted into a framework. My goal is to directly integrate this native project into a KMM (Kotlin Multiplatform Mobile) setup, where the Android side has already been accomplished with build scripts. As a git submodule, the project can operate independently and also function as a component within the KMM project.
Now, I'm focusing on the iOS part. I've defined a podspec via a Gradle script and attempted to use it in an empty project through CocoaPods dependency.
Pod::Spec.new do |s|
          s.name = 'UoocOnlines'
          s.version = '1.0.0'
          s.summary = 'UoocOnlines'
          s.homepage = 'http://www.example.com'
          s.license = { :type => 'MIT', :file => 'LICENSE' }
          s.author = { 'Uooc' => 'vicky leu' }
          s.source  = { :path=> '.'}
          s.ios.deployment_target    = '12.0'
          s.static_framework = true
          # 源代码
          s.source_files = 'UoocOnlines/AllClassFiles/**/*.{h,m,swift}'
          s.public_header_files = 'UoocOnlines/AllClassFiles/**/*.h'
          # 排除文件
          s.exclude_files = 'UoocOnlines/*.{plist}'
          s.preserve_paths = 'AllClassFiles/**/*.{h,m,swift}'
          # 图片资源
          s.resource_bundles = {
            'UoocOnlines' => ['UoocOnlines/*.{xcassets}', 'UoocOnlines/Lottie*/**/*.{json,png}', 'UoocOnlines/*.{lproj}', 'UoocOnlines/*.{html,mp3}', 'UoocOnlines/Plv/**/Resources/*.{bundle}']
          }
          s.requires_arc            = true
          
          # 公共头文件导进组件.pch文件中
         s.prefix_header_contents =  <<-PCH
             #ifndef PCH_FILE_IMPORTED_SUCCESSFULLY
                #define PCH_FILE_IMPORTED_SUCCESSFULLY
             #endif
             #import "UoocOnlines-Bridging-Header.h"    
             #import "HNHTTPRequestManager.h"
             #import <YYText/YYText.h>
         PCH
          # 依赖系统Frameworks
          s.ios.frameworks = 'Foundation', 'UIKit', 'CoreFoundation', 'CoreTelephony', 'QuartzCore', 'CoreData'
          # 依赖系统动态.tdb
          s.libraries = 'z', 'sqlite3', 'c++'
          s.xcconfig = { 'GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS' => '$(inherited)' }
          s.pod_target_xcconfig = {
            'GCC_C_LANGUAGE_STANDARD' => 'gnu99',
            'GCC_CXX_LANGUAGE_STANDARD' => 'gnu++14'
          }
          s.swift_version = '5.0'
          # other links flags | bitcode
          s.xcconfig = { "OTHER_LDFLAGS" => "-ObjC", "ENABLE_BITCODE" => "NO"}
          # 依赖
          s.dependency 'Masonry' 
          s.dependency 'SVGAPlayer' 
          s.dependency 'Protobuf' 
end

Upon inspecting the Build Settings of the 'UoocOnlines' target within the Pods Project in Xcode, I found:
'Precompile Prefix Header' is set to 'YES'
'GCC_PRECOMPILE_PREFIX_HEADER' is 'YES'
Furthermore, it indicates that:
'GCC_PREFIX_HEADER' is set to '${PODS_TARGET_SRCROOT}/UoocOnlines/Supporting Files/UoocOnlines-prefix.pch'
Indeed, within the 'Pods/Development Pods/UoocOnlines/Supporting Files/' directory, I find the 'UoocOnlines-prefix.pch' file which was defined via prefix_header_contents.
However, the macro 'PCH_FILE_IMPORTED_SUCCESSFULLY' that I defined in the pch file does not seem to be taking effect in other header files within this pod.
#ifdef PCH_FILE_IMPORTED_SUCCESSFULLY
#error "pch import success！"
#else
#error "pch import failure！"
#endif

xcode build alway get pch import failure！
